# iPhone UI design...!

Tags: iphone, objective-c, interface, user-interface, interface-builder

I have seen apps in App Store that have really attractive UI.When i make an app i use only the default set of control provided by Interface Builder and my app(even though good in functionality)does not have a UI that can attract people.Is there any ref or sample code that teaches us how to design good  UIs for iPhone apps.

Also I want to place a control in my App similar to one in iPhone(i.e the way we unlock the iPhone by sliding a button and the iPhone gets unlocked)how can we do this.Please provide some ref or sample code for it.

Comment: I think your second question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/816891/uislider-slide-to-unlock

Comment: As far as UI design, I've found laying everything out in Adobe Photoshop (for refined examples) or in Powerpoint (for rough examples) works best for me and then I just wrap code around it

Comment: @above....THX buddy....sorry dude i don know your name:)

Comment: is there any tutorial available to learn photoshop or some other ref?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no simples step by step description of how to make really attractive ui's. It takes both time, skill and a sense of esthetics. However, a good starting point is to thoroughly read your way through apples iphone human interface guidelines:

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: thx kasperjj......and do you have any idea about my second question mentioned above......thx once again.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no direct way to do this. You would need to subclass an existing control and implement most of it by yourself.